# Load spark bucketed table from disk previously written via saveAsTable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, databricks

Version: DBR 8.4 | Spark 3.1.2

Spark allows me to create a bucketed hive table and save it to a location of my choosing.

```py
df_data_bucketed = (df_data.write.mode('overwrite').bucketBy(9600, 'id').sortBy('id')
    .saveAsTable('data_bucketed', format='parquet', path=bucketed_path)
)
```

I have verified that this saves the table data to my specified path (in my case, blob storage).

In the future, the table 'data_bucketed' might wiped from my spark catalog, or mapped to something else, and I'll want to "recreate it" using the data that's been previously written to blob, but I can find no way to load a pre-existing, already bucketed spark table.

The only thing that appears to work is

```py
df_data_bucketed = (spark.read.format("parquet").load(bucketed_path)
    .write.mode('overwrite').bucketBy(9600, 'id').sortBy('id')
    .saveAsTable('data_bucketed', format='parquet', path=bucketed_path)
)
```

Which seems non-sensical, because it's essentially loading the data from disk and unnecessarily overwriting it with the exact same data just to take advantage of the buckets. (It's also very slow due to the size of this data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at https://www.programmerall.com/article/3196638561/

> Read from the saved Parquet file If you want to use historically saved data, you can't use the above method, nor can you use
> spark.read.parquet() like reading regular files. The data read in this
> way does not carry bucket information. The correct way is to use the
> CREATE TABLE statement. For details, refer
> to https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html

```sql
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name
  [(col_name1 col_type1 [COMMENT col_comment1], ...)]
  USING data_source
  [OPTIONS (key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)]
  [PARTITIONED BY (col_name1, col_name2, ...)]
  [CLUSTERED BY (col_name3, col_name4, ...) INTO num_buckets BUCKETS]
  [LOCATION path]
  [COMMENT table_comment]
  [TBLPROPERTIES (key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)]
  [AS select_statement]
```

> Examples are as follows:

```sql
spark.sql(
  """
    |CREATE TABLE bucketed
    | (name string)
    |  USING PARQUET
    |  CLUSTERED BY (name) INTO 10 BUCKETS
    |  LOCATION '/path/to'
    |""".stripMargin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark SQL to create that table in your catalog
`spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl...""")` following this you can tell spark to rediscover data by running `spark.sql("MSCK REPAIR TABLE tbl")`

Comment: Sorry to require this amount of hand-holding, but what is the syntax for specifying the file path that it should use to rebuild the table?

Comment: Assuming you wrote the table to a similar catalog with `saveAsTable` if the catalog is configured to the same warehouse path, it should work out of the box without any path definitions.

Apart from that, you can specify a path during table creation with the `LOCATION` clause, look here for further info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-hiveformat.html

The second statement I posted requires no path, just the table name

Comment: Okay, I am writing to a custom non-standard path on blob, not to the default warehouse location, so I suppose I'll have to look up the location syntax.